# How can i disable scrollbars in webkit browser?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webkit, browser

I'm using the webkit browser engine in visual basic, but looking at the properties I can't find scrollbarsenabled like in the standard visual basic webbrowser, or a command run time to disable.

Also, is there a method to manage the cookies in the webkit engine browser?
Does someone know the solution?

Thanks in advance.